# How to debug a stored procedure without using any tools or breakpoints

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design, oracle10g

Folks could someone please share the ways to debug a Stored Proc ? It was an interview question where the interviewer was asking the way to debug a SP without using tools. Finally he said like, in Oracle, there is something in a package which gives a way to debug. I didn't understood neither he completely explained :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, if you are on SSMS, the easiest way would be to use the print function. Each line you want to see if ti was "reached", just add a print 'line X' and check your messages tab.

If you are not on SSMS, you can create a global temp table (create table ##debug_table....) and add insert statments in your proc folowing the same logic as the prints.

All of these "solutions" are considering that you have permisison to update the proc, of course. If yo udont I really dont see how it could be done.

Comment: It might be worth noting that using `print` won't make it appear in the messages window immediately (you might want it to if you're going round a long running loop or something like that?). If you required such a thing it could be achieved with `RAISERROR`, along with the `WITH NOWAIT` clause ([MSDN ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)) If you are going to go down this route, make sure you don't set the severity too high!

Comment: Thank you Diego and Bridge. Bridge, I am sure you are saying something high end. I am newbie and my apologies, I don't really understand much the jargons you use :( Anyway I will try to understand better...